# How to generate more than specific column in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel-5

In my case it's all about pricing table.

Usually specific column in pricing table is 3

So by default is I can create more than 3 pricing but it will break the view because the view is designed for 3 pricing column in a row.

Usually I do this in view

```
<Div class="row">
@foreach($products as $product)
<Div class="col">
Pricings detail goes here.
</Div>
@endforeach
</Div>
<Div class="clear break"></div>
```

So If pricing is 3 the view will be ok, but it will break if pricing more than 3.

How I can deal with this situation?

My logic so far is create new row and clear break class if pricings divided by 3 is decimal like this simulation.

Pricings 3 div by 3 = 1 row n 1 clear break

Pricings 4 div by 3 = 1.xx so 2 row n 2 clear break

Pricings 6 div by 3 = 2 so 2 row n 2 clear break

Pricings 8 div by 3 = 2.xx so 3 row n 3 clear break

With above logic it should not break the view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you only want a maximum of 3 columns in each row, and if there are any products left you want to add them to a new row.

You would be able to do it with something like this:

```
<div class="row">
@foreach($products as $product)
  @if($loop->index % 3 == 0)
    <div class="clear break"></div>
    <div class="row">
  @endif
  <div class="col"></div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Using the loop variable [(see the documentation)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable) you can check how many times you looped. This way you can start a new row before a 4th column would be added.